# How to check AVAudioPlayer is still running?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer ,in my **viewdidload** method ,initially its running well ,but when i again coming to the same view controller that song starts running mingle with the initial song .

so i am trying to find out is the song running at background?

this is my function ,i am calling this function into the view did load

```
func prepareAudio()
    {
        if audioPlayer.playing
        {
            audioPlayer.stop()
        }
        do
        {

                audioPlayer=try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Kids", ofType: ".mp3")!), fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
                audioPlayer.delegate=self;
                self.audioPlayer.play()

        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

but while i am trying to run getting crash here 
**[image: if audioPlayer.playing]**

help me to find solution for this..

2nd try

[image]

3rd try

[image]

4th try

[image]

Comment: Could you set breakpoint at this line. I guess your audioPlayer = nil

Comment: yes my audioplayer=nil @CongTran

Comment: so you have to check if it != nil && .playing = true -> call stop() method

Comment: that audioplayer =nil if i check like this its giving me error

Comment: @CongTran i have updated my post check and give me some solution thamks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98792/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-cong-tran).

Answer (score 1):

```
if let audioPlayer = audioPlayer where audioPlayer.playing {
   audioPlayer.stop()
}

// create your audio player and set the delegate etc.
```

However I would encourage you that if the audioPlayer is not nil, you should not always init the audioPlayer again.

```
if let audioPlayer = audioPlayer {
   if audioPlayer.playing {
      audioPlayer.stop()
   }
} else {
   // setup the audioPlayer and set the delegate
}

audioPlayer?.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the variable is still valid (`if not nil`)

Try this

```
if ((!audioPlayer) && (audioPlayer.playing == YES))
{
    audioPlayer.stop()
}
```

Comment: Yes, you also can check if (!audioPlayer && audioPlayer.playing)